# PHP's explode() is not working on hyphen-minus -

Tags: wordpress, special-characters, explode

I am try to use `explode()` on a string fetched from a database but it didn't work. I have tried `explode('-',$string)` but it's still not working.

Here is my string which I want to explode:

**Expression of Interest – Join our Paint Team – North**

Answer (score 5):

If you look closely the hyphen from the string is not the same as the hyphen you use as your argument for the explode.

The hyphen in the string is the following `–` while the hyphen you pass as the argument for `explode()` is `-`. As you can see they don't match (the one in the string is longer than the one you try to compare it with). Because the characters don't match, the explode function is returning the whole string.

```
<?php

$string = "Expression of Interest – Join our Paint Team – North";
$strings = explode('–', $string);

var_dump($strings);
```

I have copied the hyphen from the text and used that as an argument for `explode()` and it works fine.

Comment: I have tried with all the possible ways with en dash or em dash. By converting into uft8 but couldn't explode. But then i use htmlentities() and explode it here is the code
$post_job_title = htmlentities(get_the_title($posts));
$post_job_title = explode (" &amp;#8211; ", $post_job_title);

Thanks for answer

Comment: This was true in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might be `$string` is not string, you can use `strval( $string )` to convert it to string i.e. `explode('–', strval ( $string ) );`

```
$eString = explode('–', strval ( $string ) );
// vardump($eString) - Now it is an array.
// echo $eString[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fix the issue by trying this

$post_job_title = htmlentities(get_the_title($posts));

$post_job_title = explode (" &#8211; ", $post_job_title);